# How to get Common list from two list in scala

Tags: scala

example: I have a sequence.

```
val example1 : Seq[String] = {"ab","ac",ad",ae"}
val example2 : Seq[String] ={"ab","af"}
```

So I want a list like this.

```
val example3: Seq[String] = {"ab","ac","ad","ae","af"}
```

Comment: Do you also want to remove duplicate elements from the final list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you start with defining the input in proper Scala syntax.

```
val example1 : Seq[String] = Seq("ab","ac","ad","ae")
val example2 : Seq[String] = Seq("ab","af")
```

Then the simple solution is to combine the inputs and remove all duplicate entries.

```
(example1 ++ example2).distinct
//res0: Seq[String] = Seq(ab, ac, ad, ae, af)
```

But this might not be the correct solution if you want to preserve duplicates in either of the original input sequences.

```
val example1 : Seq[String] = Seq("b","c","a","a")
val example2 : Seq[String] = Seq("a","f","b","b")

(example1 ++ example2).distinct
//res0: Seq[String] = Seq(b, c, a, f) <-is this the correct result?
```